# OpenCV ошибка при установке

Tags: opencv

[image]
При устновке появляется OpenCV согласно офф. мануала 
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html
вот эта ошибка, элементарное что гугл подсказывает выполнял. FFmpeg библиотеку обновил так же
ffmpeg-3-2-4

Какие решения есть этой ошибки, может кто то сталкивался?

Answer (score 0):

Откройте проект в Cmake-GUI, сделайте еще раз Configure/Generate - увидите чего не хватает. По приведенным диагностическим данным трудно сказать.

Comment: Спасибо,разобрался. Проблема в том что под 16.04 еще не все автоматически устанавливаются либы. Нужно было 
cmake -DWITH_QT=ON -DWITH_OPENGL=ON -DFORCE_VTK=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DWITH_GDAL=ON -DWITH_XINE=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF -DBUILD_JPEG=ON ..